# Unable to find a given value with memory searching programs

Tags: int

I realize that Stackoverflow mostly deals with code only, but this is a special case.

I have a simple program:

```
int main()
{
...
int a = SOME_HIGH_NUMBER;
...
}
```

I then use programs such as IDA PRO and Cheat Engine to search for the value (SOME_HIGH_NUMBER), but it is never found. Since it's an int, I search for 4 bytes.. even if I search for 2 bytes, etc., that specific value is never found. And yes, even if I hit the "all" tab, as in searching for all data types, data sizes, etc.

Has there been some major upgrade to how computers work within the last 10 years, which have made searching for integers within a program a bit more difficult? I used these sorts of programs (memory searchers) years ago, and I always found the given integer.

Note, even if I declare my int globally (outside of any function) it is still not found.
An explanation, whether short or not, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what cpu is your program compiled for?  ARM has instructions to load a 32bit value in several steps.  so you will not find the exact value in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but: are you account for byte order?

I mention this because you say `SOME_HIGH_NUMBER`, and a program that finds a two-byte int may require non-intuitive input for a two-byte int.

Comment: Don't take this as a joke, however it would be such, but there's no byte order search in this program. I suppose, that by standard all normally defined values either have "Big_Indian", or "Small_Indian".. Of course, I know very little about this.

Comment: I am, however, able to search for integer values. The problem is finding the value I defined, by the value I defined. I normally scatter through the hundreds of thousands of returns (those the program found), by doing, if they're less than value, then remove them, and so forth. However, even using this method does not give me the value I made, it just removes those I don't really need.

Oh, yes. You're right. I don't actually search for two-byte types containing this given value.. It was just to underline that, that is not the problem in my case.